# Is there a C++ unit testing library that is similar to NUnit?

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, nunit

We need to migrate a unit test harness developed with C# and [NUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) to C++ running on [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux).

We want to minimize the efforts in migration.

We are reading resources such as this:

http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle

But we don't see anything similar to NUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [Mark Bessey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407354/is-there-a-c-unit-testing-library-that-is-similar-to-nunit/1777475#1777475):  I really like [cxxTest](http://cxxtest.tigris.org/) because it's just a set of C++ header files & Perl scripts.  As long as you have a C++ compiler & Perl, it will work on nearly any system.  It also has features to integrate with your IDE (although I haven't used them).

Also, here's a good article [Exploring the C++ Unit Testing Framework Jungle](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle).  This post is potentially out of date (circa 2004), but gives a great summary of features & straight-up examples utilizing each of the following C++ unit testing frameworks:

- CppUnit
- Boost.Test
- CppUnitLite
- NanoCppUnit
- Unit++
- CxxTest

Answer (score 9):

Have You considered using [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page)?

Here is an overview on [unit testing frameworks for C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C.2B.2B).

Comment: Yeah, I'm a little confused - cppunit is the first thing on that list you linked. cppunit and NUnit are both part of the xunit family (and both were originally ported from JUnit).

Comment: ... so it should be a perfect match, shouldn't it? As far as I know CppUnit is the leading JUnit port for C++ (or at least one of them).

Answer (score 7):

We use [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) and [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). Having never used NUnit, though, I can't comment on how similar it is to NUnit.

Answer (score 6):

And there's [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/libs/test).

Answer (score 4):

You won't find anything very much like NUnit, unfortunately. Since C++ doesn't have the same strong reflection ability, the process for defining tests needs to be somewhat more explicit, rather than using attributes, as in NUnit.

I like [cxxtest](http://cxxtest.tigris.org/) because it's easy to set up, and doesn't require manual test registration.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you try UnitTest++:
http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html

I don't know if it is similar to NUnit, but it is powerful, elegant, and simple-to-use.

Answer (score 3):

I use [Boost.Test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/test/doc/html/index.html).  I used to use [CppUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main%5FPage), but found that it works in a Java/Junit way as opposed to a C++ way.  For example using setup and teardown methods instead of constructors and desctructors.  Also the Test Case / Fixture support was a little laborious since C++ doesn't support reflection.

I found Boost.Test fitted better with the C++ code I was testing.  It is also a lot more powerful.  After a while I ported all my CppUnit tests to Boost.Test, this took about a day and I haven't looked back.

As far as I know the person behind cppunit also wrote [cxxunit](http://cxxunit.sourceforge.net/) which is more C++esque.

Answer (score 2):

Googletest is very similar in usage to xUnit. Googlemock is by far th best mocking framework for C++. The libraries are cross platform, have excellent documentation and an active user base. All you need is a compliant C++ compiler that can handle templates.

Michael Feathers, the original author of CppUnit, now recommends CppUnitLite, which is a bare bones framework. Once I have regaled him with the joys of Googlemock at [ACCU 2010](http://accu.org/conferences) I hope he'll embrace it :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively new kid on the block called [WinUnit](http://winunit.codeplex.com/).  I haven't had time to try it myself but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good one called [CPPUnit](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppunit/index.php?title=Main_Page). It started its life as a port of JUnit to C++ by Michael Feathers. I have worked with it and it is great. Note though, that unit testing in C++ is harder than in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

There is one called Catch2:

https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2

Here are the advantages:

- Single header deployment
- No external dependencies
- Test names are free-form strings
- Powerful "Assertions"
- Excellent error messages
- Sections!
- Tests can be run from the command-line

Answer (score 0):

if [c++/cli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) runs on red hat, then you should be able to use nunit. worst case is just convert the c# code to c++/cli. also it may be easier than that see [How to use NUnit to test native C++ code](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/23529/how-to-use-nunit-to-test-native-c-code).

related [is-there-a-c-unit-testing-library-that-is-similar-to-nunit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407354/is-there-a-c-unit-testing-library-that-is-similar-to-nunit) [c-c-testing-framework-like-junit-for-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407354/is-there-a-c-unit-testing-library-that-is-similar-to-nunit)